# Nuxt 3 server api multiple responses

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am new using the Nuxt API features under server/api. My question is, if it is possible to send multiple responses/statuses through the connection. E.g.

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  await foo()
  send_status("Step 1")
  await bar()
  send_status("Step 2")
  await baz()
  return "done"

}
```

I don't know if it is even possible but if you have an idea I'd be happy about a response.
Thank You

Comment: Can you explain more about 'multiple responses', perhaps a detailed example? If I am not mistaken the example given will only return one response.

Comment: The given example is just a mock-up of my wanted behaviour. After the server route is called the server is querrying multiple APIs in a chain. Each request takes a while so I want to display the status of the function to the user.

Comment: I think the chaining of API on the client side would be a good solution for that so you can do whatever you want on the loading sate of the API.

Comment: I thought if that as well but it is not a good solution for my usecase. I googled a bit and found SSE but I have zero experience with that.

Comment: You can try to post another question with that topic, there are people with experience that will help you. If possible, a well detailed question for what you need.